# ManagementObjectSearcher is not working

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, com

I'm trying to get some info about `RSOP_SecuritySettingBoolean` but it returns an empty collection. Am i doing something wrong? Win7 x64 HP without domain:

```
        var options = new ConnectionOptions();
        var scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\.\root\RSOP\Computer", options);

        var objectQuery = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM RSOP_SecuritySettingBoolean");
        using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, objectQuery))
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject o in searcher.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key Name: {0}", o["KeyName"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Precedence: {0}", o["Precedence"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Setting: {0}", o["Setting"]);
            }
        }
```